# C# - Process.GetProcesses() returns Empty when Executed in a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, topshelf

I am trying to create a Windows Service that regularly collects data about the running applications on a computer. The `Process.GetProcesses()` function works and returns the processes when I am running the service in Visual Studio Debug Mode but it returns an empty array when running in an installed Windows Service. I have already set the Windows Service to interact with the desktop but it still returns empty.

The service already has elevated privileges and is being run as `Local System`.

Is there any other thing that I can do to make this work? Please help. Thank you very much!

Comment: I've removed your `[visual-studio]` tag because this isn't a question about using Visual Studio.

Comment: What was the service context of your service? Of course, it will work in the security context of the elevated debugger.